# iOS 6 Game Center Turn Based Match Starts With Minimum Number Of Players

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center

One problem we have found is that if you have a variable number of players and then start a match with "auto-match", Game Center will start the match with the "minimum" number of players.  It does this even if the Game Center match-making UI is showing auto-match spaces for more then the minimum number of players.

[image]

For the above example, even though 3 players are specified, the match will only be started with 2 participants ("me" and one "Auto-match").

Here is how the match request looks:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;    
request.maxPlayers = 4;
request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;
request.playerGroup = 0;
request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 4;
```

Is this just a Game Center bug?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. What I found worked best was to add players immediately after the match was created and increased my minimum players to 3.